# How to use rails associations from Rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, rails-console

I have two Active Records called *Ingredients* and *Category*. I have to following command in the rails console, which added a new item called *Protein Bread* in the category *Bread type*, while creating the *Bread Type* category at the same time:

```
Ingredient.create!(name: 'Protein Bread', price: 2.5, categories: 
[Category.new(title: 'Bread Type')])
```

Now my question is how can I add a new element, whose name is gonna be *Glutein-free Bread* for instance in the category Bread Type? I tried :

```
Ingredient.create!(name: 'Glutein-free Bread', price: 0.2, category: Bread 
Type)
```

But I get an error saying :

```
SyntaxError: (irb):4: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting 
keyword_do or '{' or '('
```

Does anyone have an idea how to go about this? Thanks in advance

Comment: use this `Ingredient.create!(name: 'Glutein-free Bread', price: 0.2, category: Category.find_by(title: 'Bread Type').id)`

Comment: First you have to find category and then add it to your ingredient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for better reading I think it's better to create / find category first then you create ingredients

```
# if category name already created
@category = Category.find_by_title("Bread Type")
@category.ingredients.build(name: 'Glutein-free Bread', price: 0.2)
@category.ingredients.build(name: 'other_item_name', price: 0.0)

# if it's new name category
@category = Category.create("Other Type")
# you can continue same as above
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@category = Category.find_by(title: "Bread Type")
@category.ingredients
```

which is show all ingredients related category,that is used if there is association between two tables.

Now, you can create ingredients related categories

```
@category.ingredients.create!(name: "example", price: 202)
```